# Prevent multiple login using the same username and password in web application

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

How to prevent a single user ID and password to login, after i login with different login with another computer, that time user can not login.

Then how to disable the session at that time.

Plz helps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using database:-

- update session expire time in database once the user login, this should be equal to the session expiry time.
- on user logout reset this time to logout time
- and if someone else try to login from other device check if the current date is greater than the session expiry date in your database, and allow login only if condition meet.